# path name as class name TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using gatsby, react and this is a HEADER component.

I wanna add a class on nav.gnbUl which matches pathname through onClick event.
It worked on a plain react page but this time it doesn't on gatsby site.

It says *TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined*
Which part should I fix?

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
//import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import logo from "../img/logo/logo.svg"

function Header({ /*siteTitle,*/ pathname }) {
  const [path, setPath] = useState(pathname.replace("/", ""))

  function handleClick(path) {
    setPath(path.replace("/", ""))
  }
  return (
    <header className="headerWrap">
      <p className="companyTopLogo imgWrap">
        <Link to="/">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </Link>
      </p>
      <nav className={`gnbUl ${path}`}>
        <Link to="/Elsa/" onClick={() => handleClick("/Elsa")}>
          ELSA
        </Link>
        {/*<Link to="./App">R&amp;BD projects</Link>*/}
        <Link to="/AboutUs/" onClick={() => handleClick("/AboutUs")}>
          about us
        </Link>
        <Link to="/news/" onClick={() => handleClick("/news")}>
          news &amp; press
        </Link>
        <a href="#none" title="">
          contact us
        </a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
/*Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}
Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}
*/
export default Header
```

[error messege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxnkh.jpg)

Comment: When header component is loaded are you sure you're passing some initial value to pathname prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your function inside a `componentDidMount` lifecycle or `useEffect` hook. This is because in Gatsby, at the render time doesn't have the information about some parameters, such as `window`, paths, etc.

So, at the initial render point, define your `useState` as empty (i.e: empty string or whatever) and inside a `useEffect` hook, once the layout is rendered, set your function.

```
  const [path, setPath] = useState('')


    useEffect(()=>{
      setPath(pathname.replace("/", "")
    },[])
```

You can check for further information in [Debugging HTML in Gatsby's documentation.](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/)